# Wildcard pattern-matching algorithm

Tags: java, strings, regex

I was trying to write code which does a validation for the below wildcards:

> - '?'  ------> The question mark indicates there is zero or one of the preceding
>     element. For example, colou?r matches both "color" and "colour".
> - '*'  ------>   The asterisk indicates there is zero or more of the preceding element. For example, ab*c matches "ac", "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and
>     so on.
> - '+'  ------>  The plus sign indicates there is one or more of the preceding element. For example, ab+c matches "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on,
>     but not "ac".

I know that Java does provide pattern matching with wild cards out of box, but this is more of an exercise to understand the crux by not using libraries.

```
static boolean matches(String pattern, String text) {
    if (text == null && pattern == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (text == null || pattern == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (text.equals(EMPTY_STRING) && pattern.equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (text.equals(EMPTY_STRING) || pattern.equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] p = pattern.toCharArray();
    char[] t = text.toCharArray();
    int indexP1 = 0, indexP2 = 1, indexT = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (indexP1 == p.length && indexT == t.length){
            return true;
        } else if (indexP1 == p.length || indexT == t.length){
            return false;
        } else {
            if (indexP2 < p.length && p[indexP2] == '*'){//case: a*
                while (t[indexT] == p[indexP1]) {
                    indexT++;
                    if(indexT==t.length)break;
                }
                indexP1 = indexP1 + 2;
                indexP2 = indexP2 + 2;
            }
            else if (indexP2 < p.length && p[indexP2] == '+') {//case: a+
                if(t[indexT] != p[indexP1]){
                    return false;
                }
                while (t[indexT] == p[indexP1]) {
                    indexT++;
                    if(indexT==t.length)break;
                }
                indexP1 = indexP1 + 2;
                indexP2 = indexP2 + 2;
            }
            else if (indexP2 < p.length && p[indexP2] == '?') {//case: a?
                if (t[indexT] == p[indexP1]) {
                    indexT++;
                }
                indexP1 += 2;
                indexP2 += 2;
            } else {//case: a
                if (t[indexT] != p[indexP1]) {
                    return false;
                }
                indexP1++;
                indexP2++;
                indexT++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right away, I see two bugs:

First, it is not valid to say

```
if (text.equals(EMPTY_STRING) || pattern.equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {
    return false;
}
```

… because a non-empty pattern can certainly match an empty string.

Second, it takes a state machine to do regular expression matching properly; all I saw in your code were a few pointers.  (What are `indexP1`, `indexP2`, and `indexT` supposed to stand for?  Is there some invariant stateabout them that you could write out in a comment?)  It seems that you are matching `*` and `+` greedily.  That can't be right; sometimes you might need to backtrack and consider another possibility in order to get a match.

I didn't analyze the code too deeply, but those two serious concerns suggest that you will need to work at this code a lot more anyway.